# How to get photo id with onPress function?

Tags: android, react-native

I need to open touched photo in new screen or modal window, but i can't even get it id with onPress function. Photos parsed from unsplash.com.

I've try to wrap my view with `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` and by using `onPress{}` recieve id of photo that i'm pressed at.

getPhoto function:

```
_getPhoto = () => {
    alert(this.state.item.id);
}
```

main view:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this._getPhoto}>
   <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

       <FlatList
            data={ this.state.dataSource }
            numColumns={2}
            ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
            renderItem={({item}) =>
                <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                  <Image source = {{ uri: item.urls.raw }} style={styles.imageView} />
                </View>

              }
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            extraData={this.state}
        />

   </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

I except to recieve at least photo id from json, but most of all i get errors like "undefined is not an object".

I solved this problem doing this:

```
renderItem={({item}) =>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress = {this._getPhoto.bind(item.id)}>
                <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                      <Image source = {{ uri: item.urls.raw }} style={styles.imageView} />
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
              }
```

but now onPress works on app launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in binding.I'm bind item.id to get function:

```
    renderItem={({item}) =>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress = {this._getPhoto.bind(item.id)}>
                <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                      <Image source = {{ uri: item.urls.raw }} style={styles.imageView} 
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
              }
```

And change content of `_getPhoto` to this:

```
    _getPhoto(){
    alert(this);
    }
```

So it's works like it does.